# How to call function in other function c++?

Tags: c++

The code works fine but the problem is the calculation. how can I call the Cube function to 
the SphereVol function so it calculate right?

The formula - if you're wondering - for the volume of a sphere is 
4/3 * 3.1416 * radius(cubed)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


const float PI = 3.1416;                            

float SphereVol(float num);                        
float Cube(float radius);

void main()
{
   float r,
   radius;

   cout << "Enter a radius: ";
   cin >> radius;

   r = SphereVol(radius);
   cout << "Volume of a sphere with a radius " << radius << " is " << r;


}

float SphereVol(float num)
{
   float r;

   r = ( ( 4 / 3 ) * PI * Cube(num) );   

   return r;
}     

float Cube(float radius)
{
   float num;

   num = ( radius * radius * radius );       

   return num;
}
```

Comment: You have integer division in `4 / 3`.  You probably want `4 / 3.f`.

Answer (score 7):

```
r = ( ( 4 / 3 ) * PI * Cube(num) );
```

should be

```
r = ( ( 4.0f / 3.0f ) * PI * Cube(num) );
```

Otherwise, integer division will truncate to 1 instead.
Your function calls look OK. You can remove those temporary variables:

```
float SphereVol(float num)
{
    return (( 4.0f / 3.0f ) * PI * Cube(num));
}  

float Cube(float radius)
{
   return (radius * radius * radius );       
}
```

Comment: @MohammedFahad if taocp's answer worked for you, please accept it as the answer :-)

Comment: One side thing to note is that 4.0 or 3.0 is in double type. You may need to use 4.0f and 3.0f instead as others are all in float, so this neglects type casting a bit. Just in case.